# chromium browser: "Aw, snap" when too many windows/tabs are open

Tags: chrome, limit, browser

I have noticed, when I open more than 15 chromium instances (windows or tabs), I get the "AW, Snap" error Page:

[image]

Seems to me there is some limit how many instances can be running at the same time. I am wondering:

**Where does this limit come from?**

**How can I increase the limit?**

I don't see any messages in my logs, indicating that chromium had overstepped some OS-defined limit

I am using Chromium 37.0 on Debian Wheezy

Comment: Your memory is probably exhausted.

Comment: delete every file  such as `~/.config/chromium/` `~/.cache/chromium/` Then reinstall it.

Comment: @Mohsen Pahlevanzadeh - this is a new installation (i.e. new profile) of chromium.

Comment: @wurtel - no, I have checked with `free -m` and I still have 10GB of free memory. Besides, I can launch additional instances of chrome as a different user on the same machine.

Comment: Hmm OK, I'm currently typing this into tab 4 of 34 tabs, and I have another window open with 14 tabs open. I am using the google chrome version, though.

Comment: I have between 70 and 100 tabs open and generally only see that screen if an individual tab has misbehaving flash running. I'm running chrome 40.

Comment: @casey - what are your ulimits (ulimit -n) ? I have 1024 an that seems to me too low.

Comment: @MichaelBoies 1024

Answer (score 2):

You would not necessarily see error messages in your systems log, when chromium is overstepping some limits.

Try starting chromium from a terminal (rather than clicking on icon), so that you can see any potential error messages in the terminal.

What you are describing seems to be similar to [this bugreport](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=367037). The solution should be to increase the limits (ulimit), specifically the limit of open files (ulimit -n).

Comment: increasing `ulimit` for `nofile` to `8192` fixed the problem for me. Thanks.